# Trying to develop a code for k-means clustering but can't get it right. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm a very beginner in Python and trying to resolve a question for my Uni assessment where I need to perform a K-Means clustering.

The first column of the dataset is all the countries in the world, and the next 164 are dates with the number of confirmed cases for each country. I need to select a specific country (in the case, the US) and perform this K-means clustering to analyse the results.

I tried the code below, but I keep getting an error "ValueError: Cannot create X clusters with only 1 data points."

Am I missing any code of concept? I suppose the 1 data point is because I selected only US for the analysis, but that's what my lecturer is asking to do, so got confused.

Thanks a lot for your help!!

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import pandas as pd

df3 = pd.read_csv('time_series_covid19_confirmed_global_updated.csv')

for i in range(1, len(df3.columns)):
    col_name = str(i)
    df3 = df3.rename(columns={df3.columns[i]: col_name})

us_data = df3[df3['Country'] == 'US'].iloc[:,1:].values
    
france_data = df3[df3['Country'] == 'France'].iloc[:,1:].values

print(us_data)

scaler = MinMaxScaler()

us_data_norm = scaler.fit_transform(us_data)

print(us_data_norm)

k = 4

n_samples = len(us_data_norm)
if n_samples < k:
    raise ValueError(f"Cannot create {k} clusters with only {n_samples} data points.")

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k)
kmeans.fit(us_data_norm,france_data_norm)

labels = kmeans.labels_

print(kmeans.cluster_centers_)
```

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example